# JavaSource file with error in JavaEE but still runs?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, projects-and-solutions

Hello and thank you ahead of time for reading.

I have a project in eclipse that is an example from my text book. When I import the project it runs and displays the correct page but their are errors. The errors are in the java file and eclipse is aware of them. The reason for asking is now I'm doing some homework and the same problem is occurring for me. I believe I'm setting up my javaSource file incorrectly. When I create my java files in there I believe I need to have folders that are com.corejsf."javafile". Here is a picture of my eclipse, JavaEE is so fun! Oh I can't post an image.

Just to clarify I'm just starting a course in JavaEE and the sample code is from a simple page that displays a text box and asks for input for a number problem. Basically guessing the next number in a sequence of numbers like fib, or powers of 2 and such.

```
package **com.corejsf**;

import **java.io**.Serializable;
import **java.util**.ArrayList;

public class ProblemBean implements **Serializable** {
   private **ArrayList<Integer>** sequence; 
   private int solution;

   public **ProblemBean()** {}

   public **ProblemBean(int[] values, int solution)** {
      **sequence** = new **ArrayList<Integer>**();
      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
         **sequence**.add(values[i]);
      this.solution = solution;
   }

   public **ArrayList<Integer>** getSequence() { return **sequence;** }
   public void setSequence(**ArrayList<Integer>** newValue) { 
               **sequence** = newValue; 
   }

   public int getSolution() { return solution; }
   public void setSolution(int newValue) { solution = newValue; }
}
```

Here is the code from the java text example problem. All the errors are in bold.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. Thank peers, the projects build path was missing some how. To fix this problem(in eclipse) follow these actions:

1. Right click on your project.
2. Select "Build Path" under this pop down menu select "Configure Build Path..."
3. I saw an error over my "JRE System Library [jdk 1.8.0_51] (unbound)"
4. Double click on the above quoted text.
5. Once the new window pops up "JRE System Library" go under "Alternate JRE:"
6. Ensure you can use the drop down menu to select the proper jdk you need. For    example I need to select jdk1.8.0_60.
7. Press finish and you should be ready to rock! Happy coding all!